# Como hacer la validación para obtener el informe de odoo

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

En el popup de odoo que estoy editando añadí un filtro mas que busca busca por tipo empleado y destino a la vez con la finalidad de obtener cuantos registros tiene un empleado  de un destino en especifico pero a la hora de hacer dicha consulta me descarga el reporte vacío y solo muestra el encabezado de la tabla pero no la infomracio´n de la tabla incluso en la función puse un logger para ver que esta regresando y no me esta regresando nada

Adjunto codigo:

```
import json
import io
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de inicio")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Fecha final')
type_transport = fields.Selection(
    [('c', 'Cotizaciones'), ('a', 'Aereo'), ('m', 'Maritmo'), ('t', 'Terrestre'), ('f', 'Ferias'),
     ('i', 'Importacion')], string='Tipo de cotizacion', default='c', required=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))

    logger.info('***********************Eligio ver algun tipo de cotización*************%s******' % self.type_transport)

    if self.type_transport == 'c' and self.seller_id and self.country_arrival:
        for rec in seller:
          for rec in country:
             for so in sales_order:
                  if so.country_arrival == rec['id'] and so.seller_id == rec['id'] and so.date_order:
                        res = {
                            'name': so.name,
                            'date': so.date_order,
                            'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                            'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                            'freight': so.freight_type,
                            'gross': so.gross_weight,
                            'volume': so.volume,
                            'invoice': so.invoice_amount,
                            'types': so.type_transport
                        }
                        result.append(res)
                        logger.info( '**********Esta viendo todas las cotizaciones de un empleado y destino***{0}****'.format(res))

data = {
        'ids': self,
        'model': 'sale_report_general',
        'form': result,
        'seller_id': seller,
        'country_arrival': country,
        'no_value': False,
        'employee': self.seller_id.name,
        'country': self.country_arrival.name,
        'from_date': self.from_date,
        'to_date': self.to_date,
        'types': self.type_transport
    }
    return data
def get_ventas_report(self):
    data = self._get_data()
    logger.info('**************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

    if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value'] = True
        return data
```

esa es la estructura del modelo y el código de python y `if self.type_transport == 'c' and self.seller_id and self.country_arrival:` esa es la función donde empieza ese filtro supuestamente va buscar el nombre del empleado y luego el destino y si existen y el id es igual va arrogar cierta información le añadi el date_order porque de ahí partí como el reporte general y el reusltado deberia de ser que por ejemplo yo consulto de un empleado y destino existente en los registros va arrogar el informe con dicha infomracion de lo contrario si existe el destino pero no el empleado etc lo deberia de mandar vacio y segun yo el filtro va asi como lo estructure pero exista registro o no, ese me lo manda vacio que puedo hacer para corregir ese error

adjunto imagenes de lo que me arroga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es una cosulta que estoy tratando de hacer en este caso si tengo un registro existente con esas caractristicas pero asi es como me devuelve el reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo manda vacio pero no entinedo porque ya que si hay un registro con esos datos en el modelo del cual esta mandando llmar la información